# How to make an auto increment key in SQL Server that resets to 0 on every day start?

Tags: sql-server

I want to make an auto increment key in SQL Server which starts at 0 (zero) on every day start.

Can anyone tell me that query?

Comment: Are you using sql server or mysql? They are not the same thing. Regardless of the actual DBMS this seems a bit silly. You could probably achieve this with ROW_NUMBER and partition by date.

Comment: Do you need this data to persist or can it can calculated on the fly? If you need it to persist then you will need to reseed your identity every day (this seems like a really bad idea). Perhaps if you can explain what you are trying to do we can help you find a solution that is a bit more standard.

Comment: I actually want to make a sale system where I want to save each invoice in Data base with sale  number. And on every day start, this invoice number starts from 0. And I am using sql server.

Comment: This sounds like a choice you will learn to regret fairly quickly. Consider a customer calling in with an invoice number of 0. First of all as a customer it would a bit bizarre to have invoice number 0. Now consider how absurd not having a unique invoice number really is in the long run. The customer calls with an invoice number of 0. How do you find it in the system? This is just not a good design at all. Now if you want a daily sale number that is another story. Just use ROW_NUMBER and partition it by InvoiceDate.

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? As of SQL Server **2012**, there are `SEQUENCES` which would be perfect for this.

Comment: OK I got it.. I should you alternate key instead of that.. thanx for your help Mr.#SeanLange .. it really nice of you.

Comment: @marc_s I am usinf sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out this is a pretty strange case so I don't think there is a good automated way to do this.  But you could create a table to keep the index for a day and use the following very rough code to do it.

```
    DECLARE @indx int

set @indx = 
(SELECT idx
  FROM dateindex
  where d =DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

set @indx = @indx+1

--your statement

update dateindex set idx = @indx where d=DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) -- increemnt todays index
update dateindex set idx = 0 where d=DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), +1)) -- set tomorrows index to 0
```